# Рандомный цвет в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, случайные-числа

Как сделать так, чтобы в кнопке Tkinter при нажатии она была рандомным цветом ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я написал код для установки случайного цвета фона и текста кнопки при ее нажатии:

```py
# импорты
from tkinter import *
from random import choice


# создаем окно
root = Tk()

# список цветов, которые вы хотите
colors = ['white', 'black', 'gray', 'brown', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'lime', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'navy', 'magenta', 'purple', 'violet', 'pink']


# функция для кнопки
def random_color():
    button['bg'] = choice(colors) # случайный цвет фона кнопки
    button['fg'] = choice(colors) # случайный цвет текста кнопки


# создаем кнопку
button = Button(root, text='Нажми меня и я поменяю цвет', command=random_color)
button.pack()

# запуск программы
root.mainloop()
```

Если хотите убрать изменение цвета текста, уберите эту строку:

```py
button['fg'] = choice(colors)
```

Если хотите убрать изменение цвета фона, уберите эту строку:

```py
button['bg'] = choice(colors)
```

В список цветов можно вписывать абсолютно любые цвета в таких форматах:

1. Предустановленные (`'red'`, `'green'`, `'blue'` и т. д.)
2. В HEX-формате (`'#FF0000'`, `'#00FF00'`, `'#0000FF'` и т. д.)
3. В RGB-формате (`(255, 0, 0)`, `(0, 255, 0)`, `(0, 0, 255)` и т. д.)

---

Надеюсь, что я Вам помог.